# Check whether "Unknown Sources" is checked in android through code?

Tags: android

Is there a way to check programatically whether the "Unknown Sources" is checked or not in application settings from the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes "Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS